# Display form values in another div(display) using jquery on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It is an easy code. Maybe using $().html() or .text().
Since Iam new to jquery so plz an easy to understand code. 
Inspite of searching on previous similar posts I am still confused.
Do I need to create another js file or I have to make changes in the existing js file.
Guys if possible plz provide a jquery code.

```js
(function($, W, D {
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL = {
        setupFormValidation: function() {
            $("#form").validate({
                rules: {
                    firstname: "required",
                    lastname: "required",
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    bio: "required",
                    password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    },
                    passwordcp: {
                        equalTo: "#password"
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    firstname: "Please enter your first name",
                    lastname: "Please enter your last name",
                    password: {
                        required: "Please provide a password",
                        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                    },

                    passwordcp: "Password not matching",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address",

                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

```html
HTML

<form action="" id="form" >

    <div class="formelement">
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"/>
    </div>

    <div class="formelement">
        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"/>
    </div>

    <div class="formelement">
        <label for="email">Email-ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="email"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="formelement">
        <label for="bio">BIO</label>
        <textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="bio"></textarea>
    </div>
    
    <div class="formelement">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    </div>
     
    <div class="formelement">
        <label for="passwordcp">Confirm-Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="passwordcp" id="passwordcp" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="formelement">
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="submit"/>
    </div>

</form> 

<div class="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do it like this, see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/awsxtkd0/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form").validate({
                rules: {
                    firstname: "required",
                    lastname: "required",
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    bio: "required",
                    password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    },
                    passwordcp: {
                    equalTo: "#password"
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    firstname: "Please enter your first name",
                    lastname: "Please enter your last name",
                    password: {
                        required: "Please provide a password",
                        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                    },

                    passwordcp: "Password not matching",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address",

                }
            });

    $('#form').submit(function() {
        if($('#form').valid()) {
            var str = '';
            str += $('#firstname').val() + '<br />';
            str += $('#lastname').val() + '<br />';
            str += $('#email').val() + '<br />';
            str += $('#bio').val() + '<br />';
            $('.display').append(str);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: But the thing is that it is not working on my browser. ie. the values are not displayed on submit. Is it a prob with jquery loading?

Comment: Do you have a link? I can take a look.  Also, double check the js files are loaded and there are no errors.

Comment: Ya its nt a prob now...i actually fuhgot to load some js library

Comment: ah ha, yep that'll do it.